# How to properly include vlan configuration for preexisting OSPF routing in PT

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan, ospf

I am using packet tracer to simulate an enterprise setting.

There would be a "main" office (marked as Bgta) and other minor offices in other cities, such as Mdlln. In the main office there should be some servers and in each city some hosts.
The thing is I now added three vlans (10,20,30) for department exclusive content, but I have not been able to make it work with my preexisting OSPF routing.

For the switch architecture on the main office I added 3 layers: core, dustribution and access, but on the other local offices I only added distrib and access layers.

[Three layer switches (core, distrib, access) part in Bgta in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR7mW.png)

[Routers and Switches connecting Bgta and Mdlln in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXdUU.png)

My settings:
I've been using OSPF for the routers. All are in area 1. Prior to adding the vlans they worked perfectly to connect each city.
I already edited the interfaces that connect the routers to the switches to add the sub-interfaces I created, for example, in Bgta Router for vlan 10:

```
interface gigabitethernet 0/0.10
ip address 172.23.208.1 255.255.240.0
no shutdown
```

and I also configured the 3 layers in Bgta and assigned the corresponding ip addresses for the three vlans in the core level switch. For each switch I also indicated which interfaces is switchport access and which interfaces are trunks.
For the other city I also indicated the access/trunks

When I hover over the router it has included the subinterfaces, but when trying to tracert between two pcs in the same vlan (vlan 10) but each one in a different city it doesn't connect at all. I've already checked the ip addresses were correctly settled on the pcs, I'm new at this and don't know what I might have done wrong.

Connecting pcs that are not on the vlan works, or connecting pcs on the same vlan and city, that also works.
But connecting two pcs on the same vlan accross cities is what fails to work for me.

Some more pics of trying to connect a pc in Mdlln and a server in Bgta for vlan 10

[failed tracert from vlan 10 pc in Mdlln to server in Bgta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqomW.jpg)

Other details in pictures:

[Core switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTI6F.jpg)

[Bgta router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bdlI.png)

[Mdlln router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXTcw.png)

I can provide any aditional info or more pics if needed. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading your post and have some comments for you.

The first thing i noticed is you are using the same network segment for two different locations and it won't be possible for you to provide connectivity between the devices unless you set up an L2VPN or an encapsulation protocol such as VXLAN that provides data center connectivity using tunneling to stretch Layer 2 connections over an underlying Layer 3 network.

The main reason why it is not working is because the sender host (172.23.208.20) determines that the destination IP (172.23.208.100) belongs to its network segment so it sends and ARP request for that ip address instead of sending it to the gateway and because of the fact the destination IP is not allocated on that site, it won't get a response, that's also why you cannot see any hop on the tracert test and the reason you just have connectivity when both hosts are on the same minor offices.

My recommendation for you would be to assign different network segments on the vlans for department exclusive content and include them in the OSPF process.